# Bootstrap 5 contents of my page are not entirely centered and floating towards the left side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, center

I wanted to align the contents of my page to the center. Everything seems to be floating more towards the left side and I am trying to get everything even for an assignment.
(This is my first time using bootstrap so bear with me if anything doesn't look right.)

Here is the code:

```
  <!-- passions -->
    <section class="bg-secondary text-white p-5">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-5 p-5 text-dark">My passions</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between g-5">
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <img class="img-fluid d-none d-sm-block rounded" width="400"
                        src="pics/pexels-victor-freitas-841134.jpg" alt="Weights">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <h3>Working out</h3>
                    <p>Working out has always been a passion of mine.<br> It helps me focus and also
                        alleviates stress. I also wanted to <br> self improve and work on myself and get in shape.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <h3>Coding</h3>
                    <p>Coding is a recent endevour that has been<br>a priority of mine to master.
                        After spending<br>a long time trying to find a passion of mine to turn into a <br>career, I
                        discovered that coding is something that I enjoy really doing. <br>Just listen to what Steve
                        Jobs had to
                        say about coding.</p>
                    <audio controls="controls">
                        <source src="audio/steveJobs-Computer-science.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                        <source src="audio/steveJobs-Computer-science.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
                        Your browser does not support the audio element.
                    </audio>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <img class="img-fluid d-none d-sm-block rounded" width="400" height="400"
                        src="pics/laptopcode.jpg" alt="Weights">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5"><img class="img-fluid d-none d-sm-block rounded" width="400" height="400"
                        src="pics/puckStick.jpg" alt="Weights"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 ">
                    <h3>Sports</h3>
                    <p>Playing sports has always been a passion of mine.<br>As i was growing up, I always
                        loved watching, and also<br>playing hockey. There is just something about putting<br>your
                        skates
                        on and playing hockey
                        with friends and family.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: add ```container``` class in section tag

Comment: that does not work @Jocefyneroot

Comment: can you provide code link like replit or somewhere else you are writing and explain clearly what you really want to do text-center, align-center, d-flex, there are lot of classes that you can use

Comment: Here is an image of what Is happening with my page. The content is simply not centered and I want everything to be centered horizontally. Here is an image that shows this. I need the arrows to be in equal length: https://www.sendbig.com/view-files/?Id=914cfe5d-faad-d9e6-c5a5-9da703d0f45d (just click on view)

Comment: what you are trying to do, where do u want to put your images at the center and the text working out ... do u want to put it at the bottom of the image ???

Comment: The way I have is fine, but as you can see, the page isn't even. There is more space on the leftside of the page than the right. You can tell because the image on the top left is much closer to the left hand side while the image of the laptop on the right. I want there to be an equal amount of space on the left and the right

Comment: Does it help if you replace the class `justify-content-between` with `justify-content-center` instead?

Comment: @ProblemChild No sadly it does not. Thanks for your response.